# How to add events in CompactCalender library

Tags: java, android

I am working with CompactCalendarView library. I need to add some events in the calendar, so that they add the events like this:

```
Event ev2 = new Event(Color.GREEN, 1433704251000L);
compactCalendar.addEvent(ev2);
```

and this code will add Added event 2 GMT: Sun, 07 Jun 2015 19:10:51 GMT. how to convert the date and time to the event format(**1433704251000L**) ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given representation **(1433704251000L)** is the conversion of this (2 GMT: Sun, 07 Jun 2015 19:10:51 GMT.) date and time into milliseconds. 
So you just convert the date and time into milliseconds.